# calling BroadcastReceiver from Activity

Tags: java, android

I am newbie in android programming; sorry if my question is easy :)
I'm trying to write code that monitors the battery level on  the phone and if it is, lower some level for example (%15), create a message that asks user to plug the charger. I know that I need to use `BroadcastReceiver`class and I want to use it in my `MainActivity` class. Here is the code I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("receiver", intentAction);
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        if (level < 15){
            Log.d("receiver", "battery level low");
        }

        if (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY.equalsIgnoreCase(intentAction)) {
            Log.d("receiver", "battery level okay");
        }
    }
};
......
```

but it seems that the `onReceive`method is never called since I never see the `Log.d("receiver", intentAction)` message on Android Studio debug window.
I also have registered `br` in `onResume` and unregistered it in `onPause`:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    filter.addAction("receiver");
    registerReceiver(br, filter);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
}
```

But still I am not getting any message.
Can anybody please help me?  Should I also add something to `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use BroadcastReceiver simply dont use it. Battery intent is sticky intent so you can check it without need of BroadcastReceiver and i also dont think its good idea to put receiver in activity. You can check battery stuff in your activity like this and you dont need to edit your manifest

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, filter);
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
if(batteryPct < 15){
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `onResume()` is wrong. You will have to update it as follows.

```
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);
    registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

to include the [ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) and [ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY) filters as mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel).

Comment: I updated the `onResume` as you said, but nothing changed :(